# How to continue a program without interrupting a while loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've wrote a parser that continuously scrap a web page and add data to a `DataFrame` that is continuously changing. The data is added as a result from a `while` loop. I want to work with that `DataFrame` in the same time when the loop is working. How to do this? I want to analyse data from the dynamic `DataFrame` without interrupting the `while` loop.

Comment: Save it to disk.

Comment: You can save the data into a database a fetch it from the database in another program. Or save each scrap into a separate file.

Comment: So there is no way to do the thing in the Jupyter Notebook without any database?

Comment: I have a script that has been running for a year the same way. I have it write the new lines to a CSV file before starting the loop again. It saves the CSV to the cloud and I can access it from anywhere. A side benefit is that the data frame does not have to be menacingly large and living in the memory binding it up over time, I just rewrite the lines from the last pass keeping it small.

Comment: Another option of course is to use multithreading: start the scraper in one or more threads and use the data in other thread(s).

Comment: You can try multithreading. Shared resources might be tricky, though, if you have no experience with that.